# Linking error between assembler and C code (MinGW)

Tags: assembly, linker, x86, mingw

Error: In function '_go': c.asm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `k_main'

compilation: 
asm\nasm -f elf -o c.o c.asm

bin\ld -oformatbinary -Ttext 0x200000 -o bin\kernel.bin c.o bin\video.o bin\inter.o bin\finter.o bin\kernel.o -I "C:\MinGW\include"   -L "C:\MinGW\lib"

c.asm:

```
section .text
global _go
extern  k_main
_go:
    mov esp, 0x200000-4`
    call  k_main
```

kernel.c

```
void k_main(){
    //iint();
    //initial();
    for(;;);
}
```

Help please

Comment: Not related to your question (I believe Ismael's answer is correct) is this `mov esp, 0x200000-4` in your code. I assume you subtract 4 so that your first push doesn't get placed 0x200000? If so you don't need to worry. When something is pushed on the stack _ESP_ is adjusted first (4 is normally subtracted **FIRST** in a 32-bit environment) and then the value you want to push is stored at that location. If you use `mov esp, 0x200000` the first push would store the value at 0x1FFFFC, 0x1FFFFD, 0x1FFFFE and 0x1FFFFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual encoding of identifiers is defined by the object-format/platform/compiler, and in this case C functions get a underscore prefixed, so the symbol is actually `_k_main`.

You can use macros to do the encoding if you want it to be portable, or you can force the symbol in the C source code.